# Cauchy Sequence in Geodesic Space

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences, geodesic

Let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{n}}$ be a Cauchy sequence in some metric space $(X,d)$. I'm looking for different strategies that one could try to show that $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is convergent.

For example it is a well known that a Cauchy sequence in a metric space is convergent if and only if it possesses a convergent subsequence.

Are there similar results?

---

What about the special case of geodesic spaces? The space that I have in mind is not locally compact and thus Hopf-Rinow-Cohn-Vossen is unfortunately not applicable.

Comment: Are you asking about properties of metric spaces which imply that *every* Cauchy sequence converges, i.e. that the metric space is complete? If so, one common hypothesis on a metric space is is to assume that it is **proper** which means that closed balls are compact, which easily implies completeness.

Comment: Or are you instead asking for general techniques to show that a particular Cauchy sequence converges? In that case, I'm not sure there's much to say. Take your sequence, try to guess what the limit has to be, and prove that your guess is correct.

Comment: @LeeMosher I'm asking for general techniques to show that a particular Cauchy sequence converges. Unfortunately my guess is not very precise (the limit of this sequence under a weaker but complete topology) and therefore I have problems to show that my guess is correct.